# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise very slow startup

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have the same version of VS 2015 at home and work; at work on a win7 machine it starts very fast (even with a solution of more than 100 projects!), taking roughly 10-15 seconds.
At home on a win10, it starts very slow (around 2 mins) with a solution of only 20 projects. Once it starts, everything is fine; just the startup very slow. 
I saw other posts talking about uninstalling Node.js tool which I did; but it makes no difference. I also disabled setting synchronisation.

Any other suggestion to fix this?

Comment: It's too broad. It depends hardware/network and extensions installed.

Comment: @qxg I feel it's not hardware/network related; rather some configuration setting issue. Will be surprised if I am the only one having such a problem.

Comment: You aren't the only one.    Pretty much anyone that has done development for a year or so has the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the **.suo** file in the project directory.
Then start it up.
I had that problem in MSVS 2010.

Comment: wow! Looks like this has done it! The startup is much faster now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry but after I restarted my machine the slow start up still exists.